# Animation blocking

Tags: animation

Just about the first real stage of animation is blocking, figuring out the key poses and timing. I generally use constant interpolation to do this, but I seem to recall seeing somewherea more "official" and non-destructive way to block out animations. What would this feature be, and where is it located?

Comment: I use the tiny loudpeaker icon at the left in the Dopesheet.  That blocks out the entire strip though, not just sections of it.

Comment: That's not what I mean by blocking...I don't mean disabling animations, I mean only seeing changes at keyframes...

Comment: Ah, the confusion came from your need to have a  "non-destructive way to block out animations". In my technical career the term 'Blocking out' means to disable.